# chalk - Error [ERR_REQUIRE_ESM]: require() of ES Module

Tags: node.js, chalk

Hi tried to install chalk on my very simple app and then i got error:

```
Error [ERR_REQUIRE_ESM]: require() of ES Module my-file-is-here  and chalk\node_modules\chalk\source\index.js from my-file-is-here not supported.
Instead change the require of index.js in my-file-is-here to a dynamic import() which is available in all CommonJS modules.
    at Object.<anonymous> (`my-file-is-here`) {
  code: 'ERR_REQUIRE_ESM'
}
```

thats my code:

```
const os = require("os")
const chalk = require("chalk")

console.log("app running")
```

Comment: I am having the same issue

Comment: @Khanakia The fastest solution here would be to downgrade the chalk package to 4.1.2. It solved the issue for me.

Answer (score 166, accepted):

Chalk 5 has changed to ESM. They provide a link to better understand what that means: [Pure ESM](https://gist.github.com/sindresorhus/a39789f98801d908bbc7ff3ecc99d99c).

From chalk README:

> IMPORTANT: Chalk 5 is ESM. If you want to use Chalk with TypeScript or a build tool, you will probably want to use Chalk 4 for now.

As of this reply, the last version of chalk 4 is `4.1.2`.

Comment: Thank you so much. I had a big issue with downgrading. If it's recommended then I guess it's kinda "ok"

Comment: Just put `"chalk": "^4",` in your package.json. Not that they updated the package in the meantime.

Answer (score 120):

That is something to do with the version you are using which is I think 5.0.0. Use chalk@4.1.2 instead

1. `npm uninstall chalk`

then

2. `npm i chalk@4.1.2`

now you can run your code

```
const chalk = require('chalk');
console.log(chalk.blue('Hello world!'));
```

Comment: It's Work for me

Comment: note: 2.4.1 is too old. 4.1.2 suggested by the above answer is better

Answer (score 21):

### To use `chalk^5` instead `4`

You can use `dynamic import` with chalk^5 `(ESM version)` in `CJS`

```
const chalk = import("chalk").then(m=>m.default);

// Option 1
async function main(){
  console.log((await chalk).gray(">", ...commands));
}

// Option 2
async function main2(){
  const _chalk = await chalk;
  console.log(_chalk.gray(">", ...commands));
}
```

Downgrading to `v4` is not a long term solution. You should be using version `v5` to be ready for ESM

Answer (score 20):

**Step-1**
npm uninstall chalk       (delete all chalk files)

---

**Step-2**
npm install chalk@4.1.0

```js
const chalk = require("chalk");
console.log(chalk.green("Hello World"));
```

---

Done

Comment: A good answer will always include an explanation why this would solve the issue, so that the OP and any future readers can learn from it.

Comment: Agree with the above, but a good explanation is provided in the answer by AJ Gray: https://stackoverflow.com/a/70425265/2701497.

Comment: These steps solved the issue for me btw.

Answer (score 3):

> const chalk=require('chalk');
> ^ Error [ERR_REQUIRE_ESM]: require() of ES Module C:\index.js from C:\index.js not supported.Instead change the require
> of C:\index.js in C:\index.js to a dynamic import() which is available
> in all CommonJS modules.   at Object. (C:\index.js) {
> code: 'ERR_REQUIRE_ESM' }

**If you got the error like above**

*Answer:* Chalk 5 is ESM. If you want to use Chalk with TypeScript or a build tool, you will probably want to use Chalk 4 for now

*solution:*

**step1: npm uninstall chalk**

**step2: npm install chalk@4.1.2**

Answer (score 1):

Just use version 4 not 5. Latest version has been moved to esm

Answer (score 1):

```
const chalk = await (await (eval(`import('chalk')`) as Promise<typeof import('chalk')>)).default;
```

You can try to use this one.

Comment: This is unneccesarily complicated. Just use `(await import('chalk')).default` and the type would be inferred automatically.

Comment: I tried this one and not work for me.

Answer (score 0):

- Add `"type": "module"` to your package.json.
- Replace `"main": "index.js"` with `"exports": "./index.js"` in your `package.json`.
- Update the "engines" field in package.json to Node.js 12: "node": "^12.20.0 || ^14.13.1 || >=16.0.0".
- Remove `'use strict';` from all JavaScript files.
- Replace all `require()/module.export` with `import/export`.

Use only full relative file paths for `imports: import x from '.'`; → `import x from './index.js';`.

If you have a TypeScript type definition (for example `index.d.ts`), update it to use ESM imports/exports.

Optional but recommended, use the `node: protocol` for imports.

Comment: A good answer will always include an explanation why this would solve the issue, so that the OP and any future readers can learn from it.

Comment: Can you explain why these things should be done, please?

Answer (score 0):

I simply used `import chalk from "chalk"`
and added `"type": "module"` in the `package.json` file which enabled es6 module worked for me quite well.

Comment: This way is ok but could break the app, and has to re-writing entries import from previous which using commonjs

Answer (score 0):

in any such case, use
`import chalk from 'chalk';`
// but before using that first you need to do some minor changes
// in the package.json file, change the type to module, for e.g.
`"type" : "module"`

Answer (score 0):

**Solution for Integrating Chalk v4/v5 with Esbuild: ESM Shim Technique - October 23, 2023**

When integrating the latest versions of `chalk` (v4 or v5) in a project utilizing `esbuild`, you may encounter issues due to their use of ESM and dynamic imports. To resolve this, you can incorporate a shim during the build process that appropriately handles the dynamic imports, ensuring smooth compilation.

I've documented the complete process and provided helpful resources in this [Gist](https://gist.github.com/Jamie-BitFlight/d15ad615249d60b02dfb72e0162ad5f9). However, I'll outline the crucial adaptation here for convenience.

Create a build script (e.g., `esbuild-buildscript-with-dynamic-require-shim.mjs` or `build.mjs`) and include the following shim, which introduces a compatibility layer for handling ESM dynamic imports:

```js
const ESM_REQUIRE_SHIM = `
await (async () => {
  // ... [omitted for brevity, refer to original post or Gist]
})();
`;

// Configuration for your esbuild
const buildOptions = {
  // ... other options
  banner: { js: ESM_REQUIRE_SHIM }, // Injects the shim as a header in your output files
  bundle: true,
  format: "esm",
  target: "esnext",
  platform: "node",
};

// Execute the build with the options
esbuild.build(buildOptions).catch(() => process.exit(1));
```

This code snippet originates from an issue resolution discussed in the esbuild GitHub repository. The essential aspect is the `ESM_REQUIRE_SHIM`, injected as a banner/header in each output file, which reconciles `esbuild`'s handling of ESM modules with the expectations of packages like `chalk`.

By including this shim in your build configuration, the issue should be resolved regardless of your build system or orchestrator (e.g., webpack, nx, svelte, etc.). The Gist also contains specific guides for various build systems, illustrating, for instance, how to integrate this solution into an `@nx/esbuild` configuration.

For a practical reference, you can view my recent implementation in this [esbuild script](https://github.com/bitflight-devops/github-action-readme-generator/blob/main/scripts/esbuild.mjs), complemented by the respective [tsconfig.json](https://github.com/bitflight-devops/github-action-readme-generator/blob/main/tsconfig.json) and [package.json](https://github.com/bitflight-devops/github-action-readme-generator/blob/main/package.json) for additional context.

I welcome any feedback or critiques on the repository's code – open discourse drives improvement!

**Note:** This approach hinges on the specifics of esbuild's capabilities and the nature of ESM packages. Ensure compatibility with your project's dependencies and constraints.

Comment: did you use any generative AI at all in the writing of this answer post?

Answer (score -1):

Think it's ES module and works in `import` way, but you can do something like this:

```
const { chalk } = require("chalk");
```

It worked for me when I worked with firebase in v8 style.

Answer (score -4):

**//First Change in you Package.json**

```
"main": "app.js",
"type": "module",//use this line
```

**//Second change in App.js**

```
import os from 'os' //  const os = require("os")

import chalk from 'chalk';//const chalk = require("chalk")
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).