# Getting error while using node js "chalk" module

Tags: node.js, npm, chalk

I want to use node js chalk module but I am getting the following error

```
let chalk = require('chalk');
            ^

Error [ERR_REQUIRE_ESM]: require() of ES Module F:\Bhaskar\Learning\CompleteWebDevelopmentCourse\node_modules\chalk\source\index.js from F:\Bhaskar\Learning\CompleteWebDevelopmentCourse\NodeJs\npm.js not supported.
Instead change the require of index.js in F:\Bhaskar\Learning\CompleteWebDevelopmentCourse\NodeJs\npm.js to a dynamic import() which is available in all CommonJS modules.
    at Object.<anonymous> (F:\Bhaskar\Learning\CompleteWebDevelopmentCourse\NodeJs\npm.js:1:13) {
  code: 'ERR_REQUIRE_ESM'
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [chalk - Error \[ERR\_REQUIRE\_ESM\]: require() of ES Module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70309135/chalk-error-err-require-esm-require-of-es-module)